# Swagger models, dataType for case class definition

Tags: scala, swagger

I have the following case class

```
case class AccountId(value: Long) extends EntityId(value)
```

And I use it in many DTOs, such as:

```
case class GetAccount(
                     @ApiModelProperty(dataType = "long")
                     id: AccountId,
                     email: Email
                     )
```

But in every dto in which I use `AccountId` I have to add ApiModelProperty to properly display the model structure in swagger.

Is it possible to annotate only the `AccountIt` case class definition and avoid the redundant code?